# C++ address handling (pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I need to track my current location in a data buffer (which will be used as a packet), so I am using two variables, bufferLoc and dataBuffer.

```
char dataBuffer[8192];
char** bufferLoc;
```

I am pointing to the starting location of dataBuffer with bufferLoc. But incrementing bufferLoc does not affect its physical address in memory.

```
bufferLoc = (char**)&dataBuffer;

cout << &bufferLoc << endl;

bufferLoc++;

cout << &bufferLoc << endl;
```

These two prints will output the same location. Does my error have to do with type casting, with bufferLoc itself, or something completely different?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to scan through dataBuffer one byte at a time, then the second variable should be a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer.

```
char* bufferLoc;
```

then print it out without the ampersand:

```
cout << (unsigned int *)bufferLoc << endl;
```

note that cout will try to print your variable as text unless you cast to an unsigned int*

Comment: That and the fact that `&bufferLoc` is what's being printed, which is the address (**on the stack**) of the pointer...

Comment: Why the cast to `unsigned int *`?

Comment: @Hurkyl Because it would print the string instead of the address without that cast.

Comment: Oh duh. (I would have used `void*` though)

Answer (score 0):

`cout << &bufferLoc << endl;`

prints the address of bufferLoc. This address is always the same. You can print the value stored in bufferLoc:

`cout << bufferLoc << endl;`

this value is the address of dataBuffer initially, when you increment it, it will be 4 bytes greater in the second print statement.

`dataBuffer` itself stores a pointer to a `char` array of 8192 bytes. What you want to do is to get this value:

`char *bufferLoc = dataBuffer;`

and increment this value. Note that type of bufferLoc is a pointer to a char array (just as dataBuffer). After assigning the address stored in dataBuffer to bufferLoc, you can print the first element: like this: `cout << bufferLoc[0] << end`.